# LOGGER.info and LOGGER.debug showing in red with cannot resolve method

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

> ***Fixed***
>
> I tried reinstalling the plugin but that didn't work so i completely
>   cleared my inteljii idea and installed it again and it seems to be
>   working. Not sure what the issue was really.

`LOGGER.info` and `LOGGER.debug` showing in red in IntelliJ idea with the message `cannot resolve method`, while everything else `lombok` related seems to be working.

*Version information:*

```
IDEA Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-191.6707.61, built on April 16, 2019
JDK Version: 1.8.0_201
OS Type & Version: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Lombok Plugin Version: v0.25-2019.1
Lombok Dependency Version: 1.16.18
```

*Additional information:*

- `Annotation processing` under `Compiler` is enabled
- Lombok is enabled in the project
- `@log` support is enabled
- Tried adding missing lombok dependency warning, didn't work
- In `lombok.config`: `lombok.log.fieldName=LOGGER`

I have tried making another project from scratch and the issue persists:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/zBamc4T]

Comment: It does not have import for lombok. Only similar to that would be "import org.slf4j.Logger;" but it is not the one i want. From examples i googled i don't need more imports beyond "import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;"

Comment: You have `Logger` in your code. Did you tried `LOGGER`?

Comment: use log instead of Logger because Lombok

Comment: In the screenshot you have `Logger.info (..)`, should it be `LOGGER.info (...)` instead, as you said you have in lombok.config?

Comment: Forgot to add it for the test project. Added it now but still doesn't work.

Comment: It did compile yes.

I managed to get it working. Edited my post to see what i did.

Answer (score 4):

Upon reading [lombok documention on loggers](https://projectlombok.org/features/log) it should be `log.info` instead of `Logger.info`, isn't it?

If configuration `lombok.log.fieldName=LOGGER` is working, it should be `LOGGER.info(...`.

Comment: Forgot to add it for the test project. Added it now but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that your `lombok.config` file where you define `lombok.log.fieldName=LOGGER` is at the correct location?

According to https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration:

> You can create lombok.config files in any directory and put
>   configuration directives in it. These apply to all source files in
>   this directory and all child directories.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you've added Log4j or Logback dependencies in your `pom.xml` or gradle